# AWS CLI command inside bash script can't locate file

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I need to move number of files from one server into S3 with some requirements:

- Save transfer progress when connection drops
- In case of connection drop, next run must continue with non-uploaded files
- Run as service -- TODO

So this is what I have, it's not complete, because I'm having an issue with locating a file when running command from within script, and yet command works when running it raw.

How to make script find the $source file from within this script? Also, is there any better ways of doing this?

Command:

```
aws s3 cp '/var/www/files/folder/file1.mp4' 's3://s3-public/folder/file1.mp4'
```

Error:

```
script.sh: line 20: aws s3 cp '/var/www/files/folder/file1.mp4' 's3://s3-public/folder/file1.mp4': No such file or directory
```

Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws_bucket='s3://s3-public/'
home='/home/user/'
files='/var/www/files/'
input="${home}videos_list.txt"
output="${home}videos_done.txt"

videos_list='()'
videos_done='()'

arrays_hydrate() {
    mapfile -t videos_list < "$input"
    mapfile -t videos_done < "$output"
}

aws_init() {
    for index in "${!videos_list[@]}"
    do
        source="${videos_list[$index]}"
        destination=$( echo "${videos_list[$index]}" | sed -e "s#^$files##" )
        length="${#source}"

        if [ "$length" -ne "0" ]; then
            command="aws s3 cp '${source}' '${aws_bucket}${destination}'"

            echo "$command"
            $( "$command" ) &
        fi
    done
}

init() {
    arrays_hydrate
    aws_init
}

init

exit 0
```

Comment: @ruakh, question about your edit history. The comment in Rev.2 was a mistake or should this post be bit cleaned up?

Comment: I rolled back my edit because *part* of the code dump is necessary in order for the question to make sense. But you should still edit the question per https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve; you've posted much more code than is relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `command` parameter contains `aws s3 cp '/var/www/files/folder/file1.mp4' 's3://s3-public/folder/file1.mp4'` (as your does), then this:

```
$( "$command" ) &
```

is equivalent to this:

```
$( "aws s3 cp '/var/www/files/folder/file1.mp4' 's3://s3-public/folder/file1.mp4'" ) &
```

which obviously isn't what you want: you don't have any program named `aws s3 cp '/var/www/files/folder/file1.mp4' 's3://s3-public/folder/file1.mp4'`.

Instead, you want to call the `aws` program with the arguments `s3`, `cp`, `/var/www/files/folder/file1.mp4`, and `s3://s3-public/folder/file1.mp4`:

```
command=(aws s3 cp "$source" "$aws_bucket$destination")

echo "${command[@]}"
"${command[@]}" &
```

(where the `parameter_name=(value value value value)` notation sets the parameter named `parameter_name` to be an *array variable* containing the specified values).

Comment: Good note, thank you. I will try it tomorrow morning.